# Intercepting Lync 2010/2013 Audio / Video Traffic (Through API)?

Tags: lync

I'm trying to identify the proper APIs used to intercept Lync audio and video traffic in a phone call (2010 or 2013). I'm investigating how the current HDX Realtime Optimization Pack for Microsoft Lync accomplishes this.

http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/technologies/hdx-realtime-optimization-pack-wrapper.html

Does anyone have any links to resources or documentation that might be able to help me out?

Thanks

Comment: On which level would you want to intercept the traffic? Server or client?

Comment: I would like to intercept it on the client.